# Using input method to select an item from a list

Tags: python, list, input

I want to use an input method to select an item from a list. I am a beginner and I am just trying to use my logic.

```
name_list = ["apple", "banana", "orange"]
choice = input("Enter your name here: ")
print(name_list[choice] -1)
```

It gives me an error: "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

What is wrong with my code?

I expect the console to print out an item. For example if a user inputs 1 the console should print out: "apple"

Comment: What would it even mean to subtract 1 from `apple`?

Comment: i subtract 1 from the list not from apple. Because lists start from 0 but the user will have to input numbers that start from 1

Comment: But you're subtracting it after you got the value from the list...

Comment: yeah my bad, I somehow managed to miss that typo